# Writing advertising XML from directory read using linq C#

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I am trying to write a directory into an advertising file for AdRotator to read.

The XML file should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Advertisements>
  <Ad>
    <ImageUrl>\002222_BMPs\Pic1.bmp</ImageUrl>
  </Ad>
  <Ad>
    <ImageUrl>\002222_BMPs\Pic2.bmp</ImageUrl>
  </Ad>
  <Ad>
    <ImageUrl>\002222_BMPs\Pic3.bmp</ImageUrl>
  </Ad>
  </Advertisements>
```

However when I try to add the  tag, I cannot get an opening an closing tag.  Also, I cannot get the `ImageUrl` formatted correctly - I only get this:

```
<Advertisements>
    <ad />
    <ImageUrl>\002222_BMPs\Pic3.bmp>
    <ad />
    <ImageUrl>\002222_BMPs\Pic3.bmp>
    <ad />
    <ImageUrl \002222_BMPs\Pic3.bmp> 
</Advertisements>
```

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        private const string folderLocation = @"c:\002222";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(folderLocation);

            // makes everything wrapped in an XElement called serverfiles.
            // Also a declaration as specified (sorry about the standalone 
status:
            // it's required in the XDeclaration constructor)    
            var doc = new XDocument(new XDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", "yes"), CREATEXML(dir));

            Console.WriteLine(doc.ToString());

            Console.Read();
        }

        private static XElement CREATEXML(DirectoryInfo dir, bool writingServerFiles = true)
        {
            // get directories
            var xmlInfo = new XElement(writingServerFiles ? "Advertisements" : "folder", writingServerFiles ? null : new XAttribute("name", dir.Name)); 

            // fixes your small isue (making the root serverfiles and the rest folder, and serverfiles not having a name XAttribute)
            // get all the files first
            foreach (var file in dir.GetFiles())
            {
                {
                    xmlInfo.Add(new XElement("Ad"));
                    xmlInfo.Add(new XElement("ImageUrl", new XAttribute("", 
file.Name)));
                }

                // get subdirectories
                foreach (var subDir in dir.GetDirectories())
                {
                     xmlInfo.Add(CREATEXML(subDir), false);
                }
            }

            return xmlInfo;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xmlInfo.Add(new XElement("Ad"));` creates and adds the `Ad` element. You then throw it away without giving it any children. You want to add the `ImageUrl` element as a child of `Ad`, not of `xmlInfo`:

```
var ad = new XElement("Ad");
ad.Add(new XElement("ImageUrl", file.Name));
xmlInfo.Add(ad);
```

You have another problem: You can't add attributes with empty names. Since you don't need one, that's fine. Just set the content of `ImageUrl` to `file.Name`. I've fixed that too.

Comment: Thanks Ed Plunkett, that fixed it!  Much appreciated!